# Not able to checkout code using TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am getting an error when I try to checkout code using TortoiseSVN.

> Error: OPTIONS of 'Serverpath': could not connect to server
>   (http:Serverpath)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you telnet to the server on the port that svn is listening. I think the default svn protocol port is 3690

Answer (score 0):

If it's http you may want to try using your web browser to access it, or maybe a subset of the url, just to see if that server is up.  Of if you typed it correctly.  It's really easy to mistype a path.

Of course, if it's not http, and yet you get an error like that, then that's a clue as well.  Perhaps you left out the svn:// part?

Comment: Yes it is http and works fine with the web browser. Even in the Tortoise Setting network settings are fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and it came down to case - SVN is case dependant, whereas http isn't.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with my network settings in TortoiseSVN. It's working now.